# ubuntu-support-status equivalent for CentOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, centos-7

In Ubuntu, I can run `ubuntu-support-status` to discover what my package support is like:

```
Support status summary of 'XXXX':

You have 11 packages (1.6%) supported until December 2017 (9m)
You have 11 packages (1.6%) supported until February 2015 (9m)
You have 608 packages (89.0%) supported until May 2019 (5y)
You have 4 packages (0.6%) supported until May 2017 (3y)

You have 0 packages (0.0%) that can not/no longer be downloaded
You have 49 packages (7.2%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
```

Is there an equivalent command for CentOS 7?